# vb 3.0: comming to Stone Age... CVDate("31/12/2200") is giving me type mismatch

Tags: macros, vb6

hahaha I don't want come back new technologies.... OMG

I found a project in VB 3.0 which we have to move to .net

It is giving me problems in next line:

```
wFechaVacia = CVDate("31/12/2100")
```

hahaha I feel young...

Why is giving this problem?

Comment: December 31, 2100. Please describe what problems and errors you are having.

Comment: Your locale says this is an invalid date. Probably, you are somewhere the expected date format is MM/DD/YYYY, or YYYY/MM/DD, or something else.

Comment: I believe that you're still not adequately describing the issue.  `CVDATE` is a vb6 (and older) function, there is no `CVDATE` function available in the .net framework, as I recall, not even in the compatibility library.  So are you receiving this type mismatch error running in VS20xx? Have you implemented a function called `CVDATE`? If so, what does that look like? If not, what does your .net call/code actually look like?

Comment: This is the Windows' function that all COM languages use to convert strings to dates https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221395(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: when I execute .exe file is giving me TYPE MISMATCH and when I debugging over the line it is happening the same, it is curious,

Comment: Not really curious at all. The locale.

Comment: how can I see locale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok

I discovered the problem, ...

Whats we were talking about locale date.

I changed to `CVDate("12/31/2200")` and it is working .

Anyway how can I know locale date?

Comment: See `GetLocale()` in VBScript help. Also see `SetLocale(lcid)` to change what it accepts. Use `0` as LCID to set it back as it was.